# Random vs SecureRandom

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Почему иногда Random работает корректно, то есть выдает разные значения при каждом запуске, как то раз запускал psvm подряд много раз он выдавал одно и тоже значение, в другой раз запускаю так же в psvm он работал нормально. Бывает так же еще что Random вызывал в рантайме около ста раз и выдавал одно и тоже значение.
1. Понимаю что это псевдогенерация, но почему иногда оправдывает свое название и иногда не подводит? Что значит псевдогенерация? Чем secureRandom лучше.

Comment: Может рандом работал некорректно, потому что вы инициировали его одним и тем же значением? Это распространенная проблема во многих рандомах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычный `Random` генерирует псевдослучайную последовательность заранее детерменированную.

То есть если задать определённый `seed` то `Random(seed)`, будет выдавать одинаковые последовательности.

При использовании `new Random()` он создаёт `seed` на основе текущего времени, если подряд создать несколько `new Random()` то с большой вероятностью `seed` окажется одинаковым и последовательности будут повторяться. Тут тоже можно почитать - [ГСЧ генерирует одинаковые последовательности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432122/%D0%93%D0%A1%D0%A7-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) , ответ для C# но для Java он тоже работает.

С помощью такой последовательности нельзя генерировать например пароли или сертификаты безопасности. Зная первые числа и алгоритм функции Random можно пробовать восстановить всю последовательность.

Как раз для таких ситуаций и придуман криптографический `SecureRandom`. Он даёт следующие числа не просто в зависимости от предыдущих, а использует сложно предсказуемые величины для генерации числа, например информацию о температуре процессора, вольтаж, и другие параметры которые нельзя предсказать.

Так же `SecureRandom` работает существенно медленнее обычного `Random`.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что `SecureRandom` намного медленней обычного, так что не стоит его использовать там, где он не нужен.

Comment: @Zergatul да, спасибо, как раз тоже думал это добавить, но что-то не стал. Добавил.

Answer (score 2):

Random - генератор псевдослучайных чисел. Вырезка из документации: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

> An instance of this class is used to generate a stream of pseudorandom numbers. The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified using a linear congruential formula. (See Donald Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Section 3.2.1.)
> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.

Это значит, что он гарантирует определённое распределение сгенерированных чисел, позволяет генерировать их быстро, но на самом деле случайными эти числа не являются. Сгенерированная последовательность зависит от инициализирующего значения (seed), если использовать один и тот же seed, то и последовательность будет одинаковая. SecureRandom гарантирует, что последовательность будет криптостойкой, но это может снизить скорость генерации.
Подробнее о псевдослучайных генераторах можно почитать в [методическом пособии](https://github.com/vlsergey/infosec/releases/download/v2017.11.21/Information.Security.pdf), глава 6.